# How to typecast uint32 bit data to sint64 bit data without using typecasting?

Tags: c, autosar

I want to typecast uint32 bit data to sint64 bit without using typecast operator.

I am implementing the Efx math library functions for autosar . And is mentioned that we should not use typecast operator on the variables.  I have same problem for  sint64 to uint32 and sint64 to sint32 conversion.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Just assign it?

Comment: @zwol probably he is paid to eliminate some misra warnings.

Comment: @zwol  I need to implement efx math library functions for autosar and in document it is mentioned that, we should not use typecast on the operator.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the "Efx math library functions".  It would be helpful if you could provide a link to a document explaining what they are and what they have to do.  I should warn you right now that it may not be possible to avoid all typecasting in a math library implentation.